# Will not paying rent in the UK due to loss of income (COVID) be reported on the credit score file?

Tags: united-kingdom, rent

#### Background:

[Landlords do not have to pay their mortgage](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/complete-ban-on-evictions-and-additional-protection-for-renters).

> Landlords will also be protected as 3-month mortgage payment holiday is extended to Buy to Let mortgages
>
> At the end of this period, **landlords and tenants will be expected to work together** to establish an affordable repayment plan, taking into account tenants’ individual circumstances.

*(emphasis mine)*

Existing tenancy agreement:

> Late payment of Rent will be charged at £30.00 if it has been 3 days overdue and then a further £10.00 per day until the account is brought up to date and arrears cleared.

There is a new law in play: https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/tenant-fees-act

Official government document is a very formal language, here is a simpler explanation: https://blog.openrent.co.uk/tenant-fees-ban-what-landlords-need-to-know/

> You will be able to charge fees for rent payments that are over 2 weeks late. The fees can be up to 3% plus the Bank of England base interest rate.

**Will being late with rent be reported to Experian, Equifax and Transunion?**

Answer (score 2):

Unless you volunteer it, for instance through a scheme like Credit Ladder or Rental Exchange Initiative, rent payments are not normally reported to Credit Referencing Agencies.

So things would have to go all the way to a County Court Judgement to go onto your credit reports, I think. With the laws you mention in force, there should be much more leniency there.

Answer (score 1):

https://england.shelter.org.uk/housing_advice/eviction/what_is_a_possession_order_for_eviction

> A possession order does not count as a county court judgment (CCJ). Eviction won't affect your credit rating unless the court makes a money order against you.

Shelter is an authoritative source, a charity specializing in homelessness.